# Performance R applying indicator and rbinding xts

Tags: r, xts, quantmod

I'm new to R and currently poking that thing with a stick till it does, what I need to be done. Unfortunately I hit a wall with some performance issues.

My problem is, that I need a CCI indicator calculated on minute periods but refreshed every second for the "actual" minute of the iteration.

My implementation works but is incredibly slow. For 4 days of forex data on EUR/USD, based on second periods, I need almost 15 minutes to apply the indicator.

I did read some stuff about preallocation and slow rbind operations. I already reduced my rbind calls by refactoring the loops. But this didn't improve the performance. So I assume I'm loosing the time elsewhere.

Since I don't know anyone who is fit in R, I post my code here and hope for some help.

What I do is basically looping my second data, accumulate the seconds to minutes, calculate CCI and after I once did that for periode I then refresh the last minutebar every second.

```
addCCIToData <- function(bars, periode) {
#bars is OHLC based on second periods
#periode is number of periods for cci calculation
require(xts)
require(quantmod)
bars <- as.xts(bars)
bars$CCI <- 0
x <- 1
##scope is time of observation == periode
scope <- list()
for (i in 1:periode ) {
  scope[[i]] <- 1 # save time by preallocating?
}
y <- nrow(bars)
lastminute <- 0
createdBarCount <- 1
enoughData <- FALSE
zeit1 <- as.POSIXlt(time(bars[x]))

while(x < y) {
   zeit <- as.POSIXlt(time(bars[x]))
   if(zeit$min !=  lastminute) {
     zeit2 <-zeit
     lastminute <- zeit$min
     zeit1 <- as.POSIXlt(time(bars[x])) #reset zeit1 because of new 1 minute bar
    createdBarCount <- createdBarCount + 1 
    if(createdBarCount > periode && enoughData == FALSE) {
      enoughData = TRUE
      i = 2
      dataPeriodeMinus1 = scope[[1]]
      while(i <= periode-1) { 
        dataPeriodeMinus1 = rbind(dataPeriodeMinus1, scope[[i]])
        i = i + 1
      }
      createdBarCount <- periode
    }
      else if(enoughData == TRUE) {
        newScope <- list()
        for(i in 1:periode-1) {
          newScope[i] <- scope[i+1]
        }
        scope = newScope
        i = 2
        dataPeriodeMinus1 = scope[[1]]
        while(i <= periode-1) { 
          dataPeriodeMinus1 = rbind(dataPeriodeMinus1, scope[[i]])
          i = i + 1
        }
        createdBarCount <- periode
      }
  }
  a <- as.character(zeit1)
  b <- as.character(as.POSIXlt(time(bars[x])))
  c <- paste(a, b, sep = "::")
  scope[createdBarCount] <- list(to.minutes(OHLC(bars[c]), 1,"CCI")) #merge the seconds to minutes

if(enoughData == TRUE) {
  data = rbind(dataPeriodeMinus1, scope[[periode]])
  #       i = 2
  #       while(i <= periode) { #improve!, we need only the last bar to be binded here
  #         data = rbind(data, scope[[i]]) #internet says this is slow
  #         i = i + 1
  #       }
  #bars[[x,5]] = SMA(data$CCI.Close, periode)[[periode]][[1]]
  bars[[x,5]] = CCI(data[,c("CCI.High","CCI.Close", "CCI.Low")], periode, SMA)[[periode]]

}

x <- x+1    
}
bars
}
```

Edit: fixed code.

Edit2: Testdata can be optained from here [Tesdata](https://goo.gl/Yqmh5u) 
It can be loaded using the command "load("path/to/file)". Then just call addCCIToData(bars_seconds["2015-01-05 00:00:00::2015-01-05 02:00:00"], 14) after sourcing the above function. I really do think, that the continous merging of seconds to minutebars is the timeconsuming task. How can I optimize that?

Edit 3: Seems that calculation of CCI is also taking some time...
For the complete set of testdata I need
357s without cci calculation
902s with cci calculation

Thank you very much!

Comment: There is a typo, as your function is not closed (missing `}` somewhere). Please also consider to share some data, or at least a simple way to get some data you are working with. Also, there is an `addCCI` function in `quantmod` package and a `CCI` function in `TTR` package. Could these functions help?

Comment: Lost the last two lines in c&p. 
I try to add some data today evening. But I'm not sure if I'm allowed to spread the data...

As for CCI function, I use that in the 8th last line of the code. Difficulty is, that I need to mix second based data and minute based data. I calculate CCI on minute data which I before added up from seconds based data. So I can not just do CCI(myData).

Comment: Added some testdata with Edit2.